# How to preserve options in Vim sessions?

Tags: sessions

I am using vertical splits to compare two files which cannot be compared with `diff`.

I don’t know how to save specific settings in the session.

Here is how I proceed:

1. enable the settings:

```
     :set nowrap
     :set scrollbind
     :set cursorbind
     :set cursorline
```

2. `:mks mysession.vim` to create the session
3. `:wqa` to exit vim
4. `nvim -S mysession.vim` to reload the session

The files load correctly, but not the four settings. `nvim mysession.vim` does not show anything related to `scrollbind`, `cursorbind` or `cursorline` in the code.

How can I save these options in a  session?

Comment: Have a look at `:h 'sessionoptions'`

Comment: Seconding Christian; this may be one of the few times where saving options in a session makes sense (in general it captures way too much). Have you tried vimdiff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for pointing to `sessionoptions`, this answered my question like this:

Step by step:

1. `nvim file1.txt`
2. `:vsp file2.txt`
3. A perfect environment to compare files.
   Note: it is necessary to apply each setting individually on every buffer.

```
:set nowrap
:set cursorbind
:set scrollbind
:set cursorline
```

4. `:set sessionoptions=options`
5. `:mks compare.vim`
6. `:wqa!`
7. `nvim -S compare.vim`

### explanations about the options:

further to the comment below, here is the usage of each of the options:

`nowrap` prevents the text from wrapping, which is important for the three other options:

- `cursorbind` moves the cursor in both splits at the same time,
- `scrollbind` scroll the two splits in parallel,
- `cursorline` highlights the current line where the cursor is.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your step 3? What did you mean "a perfect env. to compare files"?

Comment: @job_start : I edited my answer according to your question. being able to navigate both splits at the same time in Vim was helpful for me, to compare two documents that could not be compared with vimdiff nor diff.

Comment: Really thank you!